# Magento2 - How to trigger onchange event on Country in Shipping Address

Tags: php, xml, checkout, magento2

I am newbie to Magento2 framework. I want to customize checkout page where I can add my jQuery on change event on country field, so whenever I change my country field option few rest of fields like city, zip/Post Code, Address and province change and I can set length of maximum characters dynamically.
I have also created a custom module in `app/code/customshipping/shipping` containing the files `view/frontend` with layout folder containing `layout/checkout_index_index.xml` where I just added few code in order to add custom attributes to field.

I am following: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
             // do something here......
            </arguments>
        </refernceBlock>
     </body>
</page>
```

Comment: You are not looking for a PHP / XML / Magento issue. Look for how to trigger events in a dropdown menu with jQuery.

Comment: check all js files are included